# Single Article - Multiple Invoice

Tags: sql

I have a need to create a stock report, where I have article number in one stock table and Invoice number under which they were sold in another table.

Stock Table:

```
Select * from StockTable
```

result:

```
artno     opening_Stock  stock_received
30271472    1            50
```

Invoice Table:

```
Select * from InvoiceTable
```

result:

```
itemno       invoicenumber   QTYSold            invoicedate
30271472        Inv_123         10      2018-10-06T00:00:00
30271472        Inv_234         20      2018-10-06T00:00:00
30271472        Inv_345         10      2018-10-06T00:00:00
30271472        Inv_567         10      2018-10-06T00:00:00
```

The Problem is that in Stock Table StockReceived is 50. Now this 50 Quantity can be sold to difference customers in multiple invoices.

My Objective is to show data in most presentation way and then query for that: a) Some option I can think of is to show all invoice numbers in comma saperated, Using XML Path or COALESCE..
b) Second option is to join two table and for each invoice number generate a new row, but in this case Opening_Stoc and Stock Received value will also repeat for each row.
c) Third is to generate dynamic columns for each invoice. Not even sure how to achive this..

Really confused, can somebody help me suggested the best possible way to present this to business and query to achive the same

Regards
Vipin

Comment: Why join to StockTable if InvoiceTable has all you need? Your 2nd Select returns what you want. If you need additional columns from the 1st table you should show your expected result

Comment: Hi dnoeth, My bad actually to make example easy I showed only three columns from stock_table, but actually there are many columns I need to pick from it, like opening stock, closing stock, adjusted stock and then calculate their value on runtime using price column in stocktable only.. All these information are in single row in stock table, on article level, but when join this with invoicetable them multiple invoice would be there, depends upon how many different customer are sold so that total quantities in different invoice match up with stock_received in stock table.

Comment: It depends on what you want to show, one row per invoice sounds correct. Of course some columns will repeat, but it's vital info for each invoice. If you want to return info per stock, then comma-delimited might be the right representation fro a report.